# How to query a document in MongoDB using Jmeter

Tags: java, mongodb, jmeter

I have been using jmeter to load test mongodb and I am following this [article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter) with a different db
which has this [data](https://media.mongodb.org/zips.json)

I have saved saved mongoHost, mongoPort, databaseName, collectionName here

[jmeter variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uifOD.png)

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.Arrays;
try{


MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
.applyToClusterSettings {builder -> 
builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(vars.get("mongoHost"),vars.get("mongoPort").toInteger())))}
.build();

MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("databaseName"));
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("collectionName"));

vars.putObject("collection", collection);   
return "Connected to " + vars.get("collectionName");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

this connection test passes but I am unable to get read any data from the db and pass that test I am this is the code

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;

import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

try {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = vars.getObject("collection");
    
    Document result = collection.find(eq("city","CUSHMAN")).first();

    vars.put("exampleDocumentId", result.get("_id").toString());
    
    return "Document with id=" + result.get("_id") + " found";
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

error

```
Response code:500
Response message:Exception: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message}, caused by {java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host}}]
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see the evidence of the "connection test passes", if you look at the exception details:

- `state=CONNECTING`
- `exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message},`
- `caused by {java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host}}]`

So I would rather check whether you can run this query using other MongoDB client like [Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) as it seems to be a generic network problem or your MongoDB instance simply hasn't been started.

To get more information you can [increase JMeter log verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for Mongo Java client driver, it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="com.mongodb.client" level="debug" />
```

Comment: I was able to resolve this, Instead of making a connection by saving the db name and collection name and mongoHost in variables I connected that in the code itself that seemed to do that trick, but I can assure you connection test were passing it did have a green tick

Comment: I can see that you have a lot of experience with jmeter, could you link me to an article or any resource that can help me write complex queries of mongodb in jmeter